# Document library files are not in sync for all users

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

A file in the SharePoint Online document library is not in sync for 2 users. User
1 sees the latest version (Modified: about an hour ago) but user 2 sees the previous version (Modified: yesterday at 2:20PM).

Both screenshots of the users screens are taken at the same time. The file is not checked out. The users are using the same network.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed to prevent future occurrences.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Has this file been published and approved?